# How to redirect a GWT app from the client side?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

As you may know, res.sendRedirect(url) on the servlet side does not work because the GWT client does not process it.

Does anybody knows how to do this?

Thanks you.
Daniel

Answer (score 10):

[Window.Location.assign(newUrl)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#assign%28java.lang.String%29)

But in general, you want to avoid doing so, because you would loose all client state. You are better off changing the view via code, and then updating History (which updates the fragment url - the portion of the url after #).