# How to redirect in gwt client?

Tags: gwt, redirect

I'd like redirect to another page when I login successfully, but do not know how. I searched stackoverflow, [How to redirect a GWT app from the client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754230/how-to-redirect-a-gwt-app-from-the-client-side)
but this solution seems not work.

Anyone has experience on this ? Thanks

Comment: On what browser does it not work? Have you tried `Window.Location.replace(newUrl)`?

Comment: Showing aan example code of what you're trying would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to make the login happen without GWT. That way the browser can offer to remember the password for the user. If the login was succesful, redirect the user to the GWT host page url.

Comment: Do you mean different host pages can not are independently, and I can not put them in one application ? Thanks

Comment: Different host pages can load the same GWT module. But each time you load a host page the GWT module will be reloaded (and reset).

Answer (score 17):

`Window.Location.replace(newURL)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
Window.Location.assign("your url with parameter if needed");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this with a simple JSNI method:

```
    public static native void redirect(String url)/*-{
        $wnd.location = url;
    }-*/;
```